# Show knowledge article body to unauthenticated users

Tags: community, knowledge, articles

I have set up a salesforce community (using customer service theme) in which there are several knowledge articles published. But the problem is only article summary, title and URL are visible to unauthenticated users while authenticated users can view all the article detail including body.

is there any way in which we can show Article body to unauthenticated users as well?

Thanks